# Is the following inequality provable?

Tags: inequality

Can you please prove the following:

> $$\forall A \in \mathbb{R}:\frac{1}{A}>0\Rightarrow A>0$$

Comment: When A < 0 we can get: 
(1/A)A = 1 < 0, but when A = 0 we can not say (1/A)A = 1, because the axiom that tell us that (1/A)A = 1 ONLY when A != 0.

Comment: Does "multiplying both the sides by $A^2$", count as a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect.

It should say

- For every $A \in \mathbb{R}$, if $A \ne 0$ and if $\frac{1}{A} > 0$ then $A > 0$

The reason this is necessary is because $\frac{1}{A}$ is undefined when $A=0$.

So with that, start from $A \cdot \frac{1}{A}=1$, and from the fact that a product of a positive and a negative is negative. The number $A$ must be positive, zero, or negative. But $A$ is not zero, by hypothesis. If $A$ is negative then $A \cdot \frac{1}{A}$ is a negative and so $1<0$, contradiction. Therefore $A$ is positive.

Comment: You can start A(1/A) = 1 if we know that A !=0 as the axiom dictates. But we don't know if A !=0

Comment: @user149368: I edited my answer to address this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that $(\mathbb R^+,\cdot)$ is a multiplicative group, you have the answer immediately. If $A\in\mathbb R^+$, then necessarily $A^{-1}\in\mathbb R^+$.

However, accepting that statement is tantamount to assuming what you are asking about.

Comment: But we want to prove the opposite: 
If A^-1 ∈ R+ then A ∈ R+

Comment: Same thing. If $A^{-1}\in \mathbb R^+$, then $A = (A^{-1})^{-1}\in \mathbb R^+$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{A}$ is a ratio of 1 (positive number) to $A$, and this ratio is known to be positive. This is possible in two cases: both numerator and denominator are negative or positive. We know the numerator is positive, hence...

Comment: Show me an axiom or a theorem that justifies your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{A}>0$$

$$\text{Let}\ C>0 \text{ such that} \frac{1}{A}-C=0$$

$$\therefore \frac{1}{A}=C$$

$$\therefore A=\frac{1}{C}$$